# Should I mark a divorced family as Married or No-married?

Tags: gramps, complex-families

In Gramps, I can mark the family type as Unknown, Married, No-married or Civil union.

When the 2 parents was married but are now divorced, should I mark the family as married (they are no more married) or no-married (there was married it's an important information) ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is a bit of a point of confusion. Currently in Gramps, I would list the Marriage Type/Status of a family as the last known status. You can create Marriage and Divorce events for the Family, but I would put the Family Type as "Divorced".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is no "Divorced" type in Gramps, only Married, Civil Marriage, Civil Union, Cohabitation, Unmarried and Unknown.

There are details here https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=GEPS_001:_Relationship_type_event_link#6_relationship_types but I don't understand how it works.
I should set the type to Married ?

Comment: I know nothing about GRAMPS but believe that the intention is to record the - for want of a better term - most important status. Thus the couple that you raise should be described with a marriage status of married and with a divorce event. The problem with a marriage status of Divorced is that it says nothing about how the couple got to that point. The real issue is that any "marriage" has several statuses over time  - e.g. it might start with cohabitation, then go into some formal marriage then divorce. But we only want to use 1 status I think. Hence use 1 of the 6 - the most important.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding (FWIW) is the family Type isn't really intended to record the current state of the relationship, it's more describing the circumstances by which that family unit came about. Current state is recorded via Events.

All that said, if you really insist, you can add a type to the dropdown by backspacing one away and typing in a new one.

Comment: Thanks. 
Yes my aim is not to set the current state of the relationship (Divorced) but Gramps allows to set the family Type (Unknown, Married, No-married or Civil union) and I don't know if this family should be marqued as Married or No-married.
I have set the family as Married with a divorce event but No-married could have work the same as there is also a marriage event. 
Finally I don't see the utility of the family Type.